# Python 2.7.10: Adding 1 to global variables between functions

Tags: python

So basically my code is this:

```
global I_like_dem_apples
I_like_dem_apples = 0
global I_dont_like_dem_apples 
I_dont_like_dem_apples = 0

def how_do_you_like_them_applez(steve_jobs):
    if steve_jobs == "Empire" or steve_jobs == "Gala":
        return I_like_dem_apples == I_like_dem_apples + 1

    if steve_jobs == "Rome" or steve_jobs == "York":
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples == I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1

    else:
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples == I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1

def good_day (the_good_stuff):
    for apple in the_good_stuff:
        how_do_you_like_them_applez(apple)
    if I_dont_like_dem_apples > I_like_dem_apples or I_dont_like_dem_apples == I_like_dem_apples:
        return "false"

    if I_like_dem_apples > I_dont_like_dem_apples:
        return "true"

good_day(["Gala", "York", "Rome"])
print I_like_dem_apples 
print I_dont_like_dem_apples
```

When I run this, I get no error messages, but instead get this:

```
0

0

[Finished in 0.0s]
```

What I was hoping to get is:

```
1

2
```

I've tried changing the code around adding 1 a bit,

```
def how_do_you_like_them_applez(steve_jobs):
    if steve_jobs == "Empire" or steve_jobs == "Gala":
        return I_like_dem_apples =+ 1

    if steve_jobs == "Rome" or steve_jobs == "York":
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples =+ 1

    else:
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples =+ 1
```

and this

```
def how_do_you_like_them_applez(steve_jobs):
    if steve_jobs == "Empire" or steve_jobs == "Gala":
        return I_like_dem_apples = I_like_dem_apples + 1

    if steve_jobs == "Rome" or steve_jobs == "York":
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples = I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1

    else:
        return I_dont_like_dem_apples = I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1
```

but I get the invalid syntax error message. I'm pretty sure the only things that could be wrong are the global variables, but I wouldn't because that's how I thought global variables worked.

Comment: `global I_like_dem_apples` and the other `global` declaration are totally meaningful outside of a function. Furrhermore, the expression `I_dont_like_dem_apples == I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1` does not change anything. It checks if `I_dont_like_dem_apples` equals `I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1` (which is always false) and returns 0, which is a numerical representation of "false". Furthermore, you never use any of the returned value, so why bother returning anything at all?

Comment: `return I_like_dem_apples == I_like_dem_apples + 1` is nonsense. `==` is comparison, not assignment, and you can't assign as part of a `return` statement (which is why your other attempts fail).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Get rid of all `global` things, you use them incorrectly.
2. **EDIT** Add `global I_like_dem_apples,I_dont_like_dem_apples` to all involved functions.
3. Replace `return I_like_dem_apples == I_like_dem_apples + 1` and all similar statements with `I_like_dem_apples += 1`.
4. Fix your variable names, `I_like_dem_apples` is a horrible name.
5. Do not return `"false"` and `"true"`, return `False` and `True`.

Comment: 1.) I got rid of all of the global terms

Comment: whoops sry meant to do this in one comment. 2.) I replaced those statements with += but I get an invalid syntax error 3.) done 4.) done

Comment: On (2), I hope you removed the `return`s, too?

Comment: yup, but now all i get is this: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'I_like_dem_apples' referenced before assignment. this is under the first of those statements if you dont mind, can you explain what return does exactly? i thought it stopped a function or an if/else statements...

Comment: You did not remove the initialization `I_like_dem_apples = 0`, did you?

Comment: removed the whole part with global variables.

Comment: Please read my answer again. If you do something that I never advised, then you are on your own.

Comment: did everything you've recommended. pretty sure you've read the title, but just in case, im using python 2.7.10

Comment: I never told you to remove `I_like_dem_apples = 0`. That's how a global variable is created.

Comment: sorry my bad. I put them back at the top of my code, but still the same error message

Comment: An explanation of what 'return' does:  A return statement in a function definition causes the process to leave that function at that point and return to the point of the call to the function.  The 'return' also takes along with it any associated value which is then presented in the flow of control as representing the value of the call...then the process takes up with the flow with that value.  The return effectively ends the call to the function at that place.  A given function definition may have many 'return' statements but only one of them can execute on any given call to the function.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thank you so much for all of the help and constant updates!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the returns in the first two functions through "return(I_like_dem_apples + 1)" and "return(I_dont_like_dem_apples + 1)". Replace "true" and "false" through "True" and "False". You don't need the globals.

Comment: The OP never uses the returned values; your advice won't help.